# rviz Camera display incorporating CameraInfo operational parameters?

Tags: ros, rviz, camera-info, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does rviz support incorporating the operational parameters described in the camera_info message ([sensor_msgs/CameraInfo](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/CameraInfo.html)) when overlaying the data from elsewhere (robot model, tf, markers) while displaying a camera feed?

The source ([rviz camera display](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rviz/blob/groovy-devel/src/rviz/default_plugin/camera_display.cpp)) shows creating a projection based on the camera height and width fields, as well as the projection camera matrix P - the calibration parameters. These are typically described by full camera frame calibration data [rep 104](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0104.html). Is rviz not following the CameraInfo rep? Should it create the projection matrix based on the roi and binning parameters?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60818/rviz-camera-display-incorporating-camerainfo-operational-parameters?/) by [kmaroney](https://answers.ros.org/users/735/kmaroney/) on ROS Answers with karma: 204 on 2013-04-16

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

RViz shouldn't care about the binning, since the image is painted on a textured polygon with a fixed size. ROI probably won't work, but should.

Please file a ticket on https://github.com/ros-visualization/rviz/issues if you need this feature.

---

Originally posted by [dgossow](https://answers.ros.org/users/1564/dgossow/) with karma: 1444 on 2013-04-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kmaroney](https://answers.ros.org/users/735/kmaroney/) on 2013-04-16**:
Thanks for the reply, this is helpful information. I think rviz should care about binning, only in the sense that this will effect the ROI width and height.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-04-16**:
REP-0104 states that the ROI is specified in the full (unbinned) image coordinates: http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0104.html#operational-parameters

**Comment by [kmaroney](https://answers.ros.org/users/735/kmaroney/) on 2013-04-17**:
I agree joq. The problem here is that the rviz camera display uses the http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0104.html#calibration-parameters height and width. As stated these should change only when the camera is calibrated. You should still be able to operate the camera at different image sizes..

**Comment by [kmaroney](https://answers.ros.org/users/735/kmaroney/) on 2013-04-17**:
and resolutions. It seems to me rviz is expecting your current image size to match the calibration-parameters image size. If we do choose to take into account the current ROI (specified in unbinned coordinates) we will have to create a new projection matrix based on this ROI and the binning.